# symfony2: cannot redeclare class

Tags: symfony

Im getting this error message when I try to create the schema:

```
Error message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Trans in /home/tirengarfio/workspace/sermovi/src/CanalonesBastimar/Bundle/ManagementBundle/Entity/Trans.php on line 3
```

Customer.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CanalonesBastimar\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Trans", mappedBy="customer")
 */
private $customers;
```

Trans.php:

```
<?php

class Trans {

}
```

I have only one time declare as far as I know: I search into the project and there is only one declaration.. I also cleared the cache.

**NOTE:** even if I change the class name inside `Trans.php`, I get the same error but related to the new name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are missing the namespace definition in your trans class. E.g.:

```
<?php

namespace CanalonesBastimar\ManagementBundle\Entity;

class Trans {

}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! but why if I don't set the namespace correctly it thinks that it is redeclare??

Comment: @ziiweb you always have to provide a namespace, this is how symfonys bundle structure works http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name

Comment: @ziiweb Perhaps you have a second Trans class, also without namespace, somewhere else in your project? That would create a collision resulting in "Cannot redeclare class..." errors.